# Eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix and its entry-wise absolute value

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

The modulus of matrices is meant componentwise in the following.
Let $H$ be a sqaure matrix that satisfies the following assumptions:

1. $H$ is real-valued, symmetric, and positive-definite..
2. $H$ is irreducible.
3. The largest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $H$ is simple, say with eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$.
4. All element of $\mathbf{v}$ can be taken to be non-negative, i.e. $v_i \geq 0 $. (Even if $\mathbf{v}$ doesn't satisfy this, we can use replace $H$ with $SHS$ where $S_{ij} = \delta_{ij} \frac{v_i}{|v_i|}$ to satisfy this condition.)
5. The vector $\mathbf{v}$ is also an eigenvector of $|H|$; denote the associated eigenvalue by $\lambda^+$.

**Question:** Does it follow that $\lambda = \lambda^+$?

In case that this might be helpful, let me provide the properties I found so far:

- $\lambda \leq \lambda^+$
- Assumptions 4 and 5 and the Perron-Frobenius theorem imply that each entry $v_i$ of $\mathbf{v}$ is strictly positive.
- Also by the Perron Frobenius theorem, $\lambda^+$ is the largest eigenvalue of $|H|$.
- Given the assumptions of the problem setting, $\mathbf{v}$ must also be an eigenvector for the largest eigenvalue of $H - |H|$, which might be helpful in constructing counterexamples.
- Under the given assumption, the property $\lambda = \lambda^+$ that I'm interested in is equivalent to $H = |H|$. This can be seen as follows:

  If $\lambda = \lambda^+$ then
  $\sum_{i,j} v_i H_{ij} v_j = \sum_{i,j} v_i |H|_{i,j} v_j$
  and since $v_i \geq 0$ and $|H|_{i,j} = |H_{i,j}|$, every term in summation must be equal to each other, which leads to $H_{ij} = |H|_{ij}$.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm having difficulties to understand the question. In the third paragraph, why is $v$ unique (i.e., why is the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $H$ simple?) and why are the $v_i$ strictly positive? Is this an additional assumption? Regarding paragraphs 5 and 6: why is the question asked in paragraph 6 equivalent to the one asked in parsgraph 4?

Comment: Apart from this, please allow me to point out that the notation $H^+$ for the componentwise modulus is misleading. In vector lattice theory (which is, in a sense, married to Perron-Frobenius theory) a superscript + is always used to denote the positive part, not the modulus. I'd thus recommend to replace the notation $H^+$ with $|H|$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck sorry for confusing sentences. Uniquness and positiveness of $\mathbf{v}$ is assumption. and for your advice, isn't it also misleading since $|H|$ usually mean determinant?

Comment: @ChristianRemling thank you for the comment. However, I think $\mathbf{v} = (1, 1)$ is not a ev for largest eigenvalue of $H$ and not suitable conterexample for my problem setting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, but I'm still somewhat confused. Why can't one take minus the matrix from @ChristianRemling's comment, i.e., $H = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ as a counterexample? Its eigenvalues are $-2,0$, the eigenvector for $0$ is $v = (1,1)$, and $v$ is also an eigenvector of $|H|$ for its largest eigenvalue $2$.

Comment: Regarding the notation: Sure, there is a lot of conflicting notation in maths. My point is rather that, in the specific context in which your question is located (namely, the componentwise order on $\mathbb{R}^n$), the notation $H^+$ is commonly used for an object that is closely related to but different from the one you want (namely, for the componentwise positive part rather than the componentwise modulus). This is very prone to lead to confusion, thus my suggestion to avoid it and to stick to the notation that is more common in this context.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I agree. I change the notation accordingly. And also, I forgot to add one more condition on H i.e. H must be positive definite. I'm sorry for confusion I introcuded here.

Comment: @keisukemurota: Ah ok, I think I see the point now. Very interesting question!

Comment: Right at the beginning of your post, don't you want to assume $|H|$ irreducible (not $H$, and what would that even mean) ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling: I assume that irreducibility of $H$ here simply means that $|H|$ is irreducible (if one defines it, say, in terms of invariant ideals, the notion makes sense for general matrices and then it's indeed equivalent to irreducbility of $|H|$). Regarding your latest comment, I think this proves the same thing that OP proves at the very bottom of the question, namely that $\lambda = \lambda^+$ is equivalent to $H = |H|$. I think the question is whether $\lambda = \lambda^+$ (equivalently, $H = |H|$) is necessarily true under the assumptions 1.-5.

Comment: At keisukemurota: As you can see from the discussion with @ChristianRemling and me, we got a bit confused. Hence, I edited your question to streamline it and to make the logical structer a bit clearer. Could you please check whether the edited version still reflects your intentions?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I think the statement is now more clear! Thank you for the modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:

We start with the matrices
$$
  A = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \quad \text{and} \quad 
  B = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}
  .
$$
The matrix $A$ is irreducible, so its leading eigenvalue $3$ is simple.
The corresponding eigenvector is $v = (1,1,1,1)$.
As the spectral radius of $A$ is $3$, the matrix $A+4I$ is positive definite; its leading eigenvalue $7$ is simple with eigenvector $v$ (by $I$ I denote the identity matrix).
Moreover, $v$ is also an eigenvector of $B$ for the eigenvalue $1$.

Now consider the matrix $H := A - \varepsilon B$ for $\varepsilon > 0$.

The vector $v$ is an eigenvector of $H$ for the eigenvalue $7-\varepsilon$.
Since the eigenvalues of matrices behave continuously under perturbation, we know that if $\varepsilon > 0$ is sufficiently small, then $H$ is positive definite and $7- \varepsilon$ is the largest eigenvalue of $H$ and is simple.

Since there is no entry at which both $A$ and $B$ are non-zero, we have $\lvert H \rvert = A + \varepsilon B$. So the largest eigenvalue of $\lvert H \rvert$ is $7+\varepsilon$ with eigenvector $v$.

Comment: That's a perfect counterexample I was looking for! I really appreciate it! Btw, do you think we can ensure $\lambda = \lambda^+$ if we impose some additional condition on $H$?

Comment: @keisukemurota: Unfortunately, I'm currently not aware of a good condition which ensures $\lambda = \lambda^+$.